# Need TurboC on Windows8

Tags: windows-8.1, turbo-c

I have a windows 8.1 and I need to run turbo/borland c (not c++ or c#). How can I do that?Please don't suggest running windows xp on a virtual machine.

Comment: No, you really don't need that. There are many modern (and free as in no cost) IDE's with up-to-date compilers.

Answer (score 1):

You can install [DosBox](http://www.dosbox.com/information.php) and run 16-bit MS-DOS applications there.

Answer (score 0):

You can [download Turbo C++ from CodePlex](https://turboc.codeplex.com/), which includes DosBox so you can work on Windows without a virtual machine.